# To find last working day in a table using Oracle plsql

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to find out the last working day of every holiday from a table. For example, I have table which has following structure.:

```
create table t1( a char(8),
     b varchar2(40), 
     c varchar2(90), d char(8));

Insert into t1 values ('w','Feb 1', 'Tuesday','l');
....
Insert into t1 values ('H', 'Feb 3', 'sat','j');
Insert into t1 values ('H', 'Feb 4', 'sun','k');
Insert into t1 values ('H', 'Feb 5', 'mon', 'o');
```

My requirement is whenever I tried to get data for a holiday (`H` in this case), i need to take value for last working day (`w` in this case). In simple terms, my expected value for Saturday and Sunday should be the Value for Friday. Note that insert statement has Monday also as holiday and I want Friday's d column as output for Monday too.Kindly help me for this requirement in Oracle SQL.

Comment: Please edit the sample data and provide working statements. `Insert into table t1 values (H, Feb 3, sat,j)` is invalid.

Comment: Columns in T1 don't fit INSERT INTO statements (which are invalid anyway, as @astentx already said). Posting something like that is useless (while it should be useful, if you expect any help). Furthermore, what does T1 contain? The whole calendar (e.g. 365 rows for this year)? You said that Saturdays and Sundays are "holidays"; don't they, rather, represent *weekend*? Holiday is something different. Salary *might* (should?) be different if you work on Monday, Sunday or holiday that falls on Sunday so ... maybe your "H" for all non-working days isn't the best choice.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot code was edited. Yes, T1 table will have all the dates in a year and both weekend as well as holidays were updated as H in that table. In the given example, i have three holiday which includes two days of weekend and one day of actual holiday. Now my result for all Sat,sun and mon should be the column value of d of last working day (w) in this case Friday. Kindly help me on this regard.

Comment: OK, thank you. Have a look at what I posted below, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to find all the holidays and subtract 1 day from the first date of the holiday to get the previous last working day (assuming that your calendar table lists every day):

```sql
SELECT start_datetime - INTERVAL '1' DAY AS last_working_day
FROM   t1
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY datetime
  MEASURES
    FIRST(datetime) AS start_datetime
  PATTERN ( holiday+ )
  DEFINE
    holiday AS daytype = 'H'
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (datetime, daytype) AS
SELECT datetime,
       CASE
       WHEN datetime - TRUNC(datetime, 'IW') >= 5
       THEN 'H'
       ELSE 'W'
       END
FROM   (
  SELECT DATE '2023-02-01' + LEVEL - 1 AS datetime
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 14
);
```

*Note: 4/5th and 11/12th February were weekends in 2023, not 3/4th.*

Outputs:

| LAST_WORKING_DAY |
| --- |
| 2023-02-03 00:00:00 |
| 2023-02-10 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/K4A05PWi)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. This query is not working in my system. Also your logic will give n-1 as output with n as holiday.. Now of i want to check data for Sunday, your query may give output for Saturday only not Friday as expected. ? Kindly clarify

Comment: @karthick_senthilnathan The answer states "assuming that your calendar table lists every day". If this assumption is true then you will never have a Sunday without a Saturday and if Saturday is not marked as `h` then returning Saturday is a valid result.

Answer (score 0):

(Setting environment; you don't have to do that):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

As `t1` contains the whole calendar and days are marked either as **w**orking days or **h**olidays, then you could use correlated subquery (lines #3 - 7 in my query) to fetch working day that precedes any other day in that table.

Column names you used (a, b, c, d) aren't very descriptive so I tried to improve that:

- `status` is `w` or `h`
- `datum` is *date*; its datatype is (and should) be `date`; if you  used `varchar2` column, don't do it. What if table contains two (or more years) and you stored `Feb 3` in there - which year does that date belongs to?
- `day_name` is probably superfluous as you can get that value from `datum` with `to_char` function, but OK, let's leave it

---

```
SQL> select a.datum, a.status, a.day_name,
  2    --
  3    (select to_char(max(b.datum), 'dd.mm.yyyy, dy')
  4     from t1 b
  5     where b.datum < a.datum
  6       and b.status = 'w'
  7    ) previous_working_datum
  8  from t1 a
  9  where to_char(a.datum, 'yyyymm') = '202302'
 10  order by a.datum;

DATUM      S DAY PREVIOUS_WORKIN
---------- - --- ---------------
01.02.2023 w wed 31.01.2023, tue
02.02.2023 w thu 01.02.2023, wed
03.02.2023 w fri 02.02.2023, thu
04.02.2023 h sat 03.02.2023, fri --> holiday, so previous working day is Thursday, 02.02.2023
05.02.2023 h sun 03.02.2023, fri --> holiday
06.02.2023 h mon 03.02.2023, fri --> holiday
07.02.2023 w tue 03.02.2023, fri --> working day; its previous working day is also Thursday, 02.02.2023
08.02.2023 w wed 07.02.2023, tue
09.02.2023 h thu 08.02.2023, wed --> holiday, so previous working day is Wednesday, 08.02.2023
10.02.2023 w fri 08.02.2023, wed
11.02.2023 h sat 10.02.2023, fri
<snip>

28 rows selected.

SQL>
```